# How do I allocate a file larger than 0 bytes without writing content in a POSIX environment?

Tags: linux, macos, unix, posix, createfile

I need to be able to create a large number of files, randomly-sized 1k-64k averaging 32k, very quickly. One method I've found uses the unix command **dd** to copy bytes from /dev/urandom into a new file. However, I'm trying to save the time by just creating the file link to unallocated space, without writing random bytes to disk.

Is this possible in a Unix-like environment and, if so, how would I go about it?

If not, could this be done with a small C program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the commandline, `mkfile` or `dd` or any number of other (not-necessarily POSIX-standard) utilities. I would note that copying from `/dev/zero` instead of `/dev/urandom` can be significantly quicker, especially on older systems with slower CPUs.

If you want to do something in C or C++ code, there's `truncate()` and `ftruncate()`. Probably most Perl/Python/whatever bindings expose the system/libc call in some way as well.

Comment: Thanks! I was unfamiliar with `mkfile` and the 80 Google searches weren't being helpful.

Comment: I fail to see how this explains mkfile.

Comment: @awiebe It wasn't intended to explain `mkfile`. It was answering the original question.

Answer (score -1):

So you want to `mkfile {size}[b|k|m|g] filename` in cwd?

Comment: Is that an answer or a comment?! If that's an answer, please try explaining/referencing a bit.

Comment: What's to explain type 'man mkfile'. Write a shell script that loops to mkfile.